# ActiveRecord: keep duplicated objects in .where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an array of ids:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

If I run:

```
Product.where(id: ids)
```

I will only get one occurence of the `Product` having the iD `1`.
However, I'd like to get as many occurences of the object as there are in the array.

How can I do this ?

Comment: `where` does not apply uniqueness constraints by default, your query should work but could be shortened to `[1, 2, 3]`. `id` is the default `primary_key` for Rails models so i'm assuming your table is either 1) using a different primary key or 2) circumventing a database level primary key constraint and inserting duplicate (in which case i'm confused :)). Could you share some more about the schema of your model, your rails/active record version, and the underlying DB technology (postgres, sqlite, mysql?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the unique records and then transform the result into an Array with multiple references to each book:

```
ids = [2109, 2511, 2108, 2109]
tmp_books = Book.find(ids)
new_books = ids.map {|x| tmp_books.detect {|b| b.id == x } }
```

That produces an array with the duplicates you're looking for while only executing a single query:

```
Book Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" IN (2109, 2511, 2108)
=> ["Rick Newman", "Hassan Abbas", "Ms. Martha Byrd", "Rick Newman"]
```

One consequence of this is that a change to one record in that array could affect other records.  So in the example above, there are two references to the Rick Newman book, and so changing the `author` on the first record would change the `author` on the last record.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, as where clause return the array of record:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 1]

products = []

ids.each do |id|
  products << Product.find(id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it with a `.where` query but if you're ok with having an `Array` instead of an Active Record relation it is very trivial, you don't need any intermediate variable or loop, just map the ids :

```rb
[1, 2, 3, 1].map{ |id| Product.find(id) }
```