# Get repeated records on purpose through IN query or where clause - Mysql / Activerecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have an array of ids like so

```
ids = [123, 456, 123, 789]
```

Now, when I query database through where clause,

```
Model.where(id: ids)
```

By nature it returns only 3 unique records, however, I am in a situation where I want the duplicate/repeated records to be returned as well if present in an array.

I don't want to loop in and do `N+1`. I am ok with activerecord or MySql solution.

Comment: In SQL Server I would replace the ids array with a cte and simply do an inner join on `id` - I don't know the details with MySql but I'm pretty sure that's the direction you need to fo.

Comment: I see.. Not familiar with it though so a working related example query or internet resource would be helpful. @ZoharPeled

Comment: Well, I know nothing about ruby on rails, and don't know enough about MySql to show you a good example - but I'll bet if you searched for something like "how to perform an inner join with an array of numbers in mySql" you will get some ideas.

Comment: thanks, will do that..

Comment: One way to do it in one query is to do a find and then build the array; see details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489103/activerecord-keep-duplicated-objects-in-where-query/48492462#48492462